# How to audit a mirroring job?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, mirroring

I am using SyncBack to mirror two shared folders on two separate shared folders(SMB) on two servers in the same trust domain.

I checked the option to copy also the folder rights:

```
 Copy sub-directory and file security permissions (only valid for NTFS)
```

The SyncBack job reported successful when finished. But I had history where some rights were not copied or some files were missing.

How can I audit if the copy/mirroring was successful, check all the files and the security permissions against its original copy?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way using [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) which comes with [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

It has an option that only logs the differences without copying them.

The command was:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Data2\ \\srvbk1\d$\DATA\DATA\ /e /l  /log:diff.txt
```

Explanation of the command switches used above:

- `/e`  Recurse through sub-directories (including empty ones)
- `/l`  **Don’t modify or copy files, log differences only**
- `/log:reconcile.txt`   Write log to reconcile.txt (Recreate if
  exists)
- `/log+: reconcile.txt`   (Optional variant) Write log to
  reconcile.txt (Append if exists)